# Difference between myFunc.prototype vs new myFunc().prototype

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {};
myFunction.prototype.foo = "bar";

var myFuncInstance = new myFunction();

console.log('myFunction.foo:   '        + myFunction.foo); // Prints undefined
console.log('myFuncInstance.foo:   '    + myFuncInstance.foo); // Prints bar
```

Why `myFunction.foo` prints `undefined` here? where I already set the property foo as `myFunction.prototype.foo = "bar"`.

Comment: `myFunction` is not a variable, its a function

Answer (score 0):

In this case `myFunc` is not the object, it represents the *class* of the object. That means you can use the `new` keyword to create objects that have the same properties as the `prototype` of the class. It does not mean that you get a new series of properties on the function itself.

Following your example, this will work:

```
function myFunction() {};
myFunction.prototype.foo = "bar";

var myFuncInstance = new myFunction();

console.log('myFunction.prototype.foo: '  + myFunction.prototype.foo);
console.log('myFuncInstance.foo: '        + myFuncInstance.foo);
```

Comment: So, can I conclude that, in case of typeof function, prototype chain lookup won't trigger, prototype chain lookup will happen only in case of Objects?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare some variable into the `prototype` of the object you are attaching values to any instance of that object, so the values that are define into `prototype` will be accesible through instance, so when call `myFunction.foo` you are trying call `.foo` variable as a static variable, that's because myFunction is the contructor and not the instance of that constructor, when you call `myFuncInstance.foo` `myFuncInstance` is a instance already so you can access to the `.foo` variable because was defined into its ´prototype´.

So when is you really need to get access to this `myFunction.foo` you should define it as

```
function myFunction() {};
myFunction.foo = 'static bar'; // it can be accessed without instance
```

so when you call `myFunctionInstance.foo`, you should define it as follow

```
function myFunction() {};
myFunction.prototype.foo = 'instance bar'; // it can be accessed with instance
var myFunctionInstance = new myFunction();
myFunctionInstance.foo; // will print 'instance bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

We all know, JavaScript **objects** **inherit** **properties** and **methods** from a **prototype**.

In your second `log` you have a proper instance `( Prototype Inheritance )` and in your first log you are accessing `function property` without any instance (directly with function name).

You will need an instance `(myFuncInstance)` to access the property not the `function` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Every object has a prototype, when you use `.` to get one object's property.
Firstly, it will find the properties of itself, if do not get the target property, it will find its prototype's properties, if still do not get the target property, it will continue to find properties of its proertype's propertype. After these, this case get easy.

After using `new`, you get a instance `myFuncInstance`, when using `myFuncInstance.foo` , beacause itself do not have a property called `foo`, it will get the property `foo` from its constructor `myFunction`'s prototype.

However, when using `myFunction.foo`, `myFunction` alse do not have a property call `foo`, it will find its prototype `Function.prototype`, it also can not find `foo`, so find the `Function.prototype`'s prototype `Object.prototype`, it still can not find, so find the `Object.prototype`'s prototype `null`, all of the prototype chain can not find `foo`, so it is `undefined`.

Comment: However, when using myFunction.foo, myFunction alse do not have a property call foo, it will find its prototype Function.prototype, it also can not find foo
 [ I am expecting to find the myFunction.foo in the prototype chain, becuase I have already set myFunction.prototype.foo = "bar"; and during my local debugging I can see the value as 

myFunction.prototype = 
foo: "bar"
constructor: ƒ myFunction()
__proto__: Object
 ]

Comment: I think you can see the property `__proto__` in your debugging, the `__proto__` reference the prototype chain,   the `myFuncInstance` will find `foo` at myFunction.prototype, actually, you can see `myFuncInstance.__proto__.foo === 'bar'`, so `myFuncInstance.__proto__ === myFunction.prototype`. At `myFunction.foo`, it will find `myFunction.__proto__`, `myFunction.__proto__ === Function.prototype`.